# Django ModelChoiceField with empty_label as valid input

Tags: python, django, modelchoicefield

I'm using the following form to generate a dropdown list with my registered users:

```
class TaskAssignUserForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all().order_by('username'))
```

Inside my template I render the above form together with a submit button. The application user can choose from the registered users to select one and assign him/her to a task. This is working, if a user and not the empty label (--------) was selected.

But, I want the empty label as a valid option too, to cancel the assignment between the task and the user. I'm working with the following `views.py` and looking for an option to check if the empty label or an empty choice was made.

```
if form_TaskAssignUserForm.is_valid():
    task.user_assigned = form_TaskAssignUserForm.cleaned_data['user']
    task.save()
else:
   if  # check if emtpy label is set
       task.user_assigned = None
       task.save()
```

I found out that checking if `form_TaskAssignUserForm.cleaned_data['user']` exists could be an option but I feel not comfortable with that. There should be a way that works together with the `.is_valid()` check.

Is there a djangonian way solving that problem?

Bye, aronadaal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just need to set `required=False` on the field.

```
user = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=User.objects.all().order_by('username'))
```

This means that no selection is required for the form to be valid.

Comment: that was too easy ;)